# ThreadPoolExecutor Limiting Server Requests

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to pull data from a server, however when the executor runs it will make many requests at the same time to the server, but the server can only handle 4 requests at a time. So my task is to make the `ThreadPoolExecutor` only make 4 requests at any time. Below I have a minimum working example, but how can I make it to limit the total number of requests at a given time?

```py
import requests
import concurrent.futures

# Files
files = [r'https://data.pacificclimate.org/data/downscaled_gcms/tasmin_day_BCCAQv2+ANUSPLIN300_CanESM2_historical+rcp45_r1i1p1_19500101-21001231.nc.nc?tasmin[0:55114][152:152][290:290]',
r'https://data.pacificclimate.org/data/downscaled_gcms/tasmin_day_BCCAQv2+ANUSPLIN300_CNRM-CM5_historical+rcp45_r1i1p1_19500101-21001231.nc.nc?tasmin[0:55114][152:152][290:290]',
r'https://data.pacificclimate.org/data/downscaled_gcms/tasmin_day_BCCAQv2+ANUSPLIN300_CSIRO-Mk3-6-0_historical+rcp45_r1i1p1_19500101-21001231.nc.nc?tasmin[0:55114][152:152][290:290]',
r'https://data.pacificclimate.org/data/downscaled_gcms/tasmin_day_BCCAQv2+ANUSPLIN300_CCSM4_historical+rcp45_r2i1p1_19500101-21001231.nc.nc?tasmin[0:55114][152:152][290:290]',
r'https://data.pacificclimate.org/data/downscaled_gcms/tasmin_day_BCCAQv2+ANUSPLIN300_MIROC5_historical+rcp45_r3i1p1_19500101-21001231.nc.nc?tasmin[0:55114][152:152][290:290]',
r'https://data.pacificclimate.org/data/downscaled_gcms/tasmin_day_BCCAQv2+ANUSPLIN300_MPI-ESM-LR_historical+rcp45_r3i1p1_19500101-21001231.nc.nc?tasmin[0:55114][152:152][290:290]',
r'https://data.pacificclimate.org/data/downscaled_gcms/tasmin_day_BCCAQv2+ANUSPLIN300_MRI-CGCM3_historical+rcp45_r1i1p1_19500101-21001231.nc.nc?tasmin[0:55114][152:152][290:290]',
r'https://data.pacificclimate.org/data/downscaled_gcms/tasmin_day_BCCAQv2+ANUSPLIN300_GFDL-ESM2G_historical+rcp45_r1i1p1_19500101-21001231.nc.nc?tasmin[0:55114][152:152][290:290]',
r'https://data.pacificclimate.org/data/downscaled_gcms/tasmin_day_BCCAQv2+ANUSPLIN300_HadGEM2-ES_historical+rcp45_r1i1p1_19500101-21001231.nc.nc?tasmin[0:55114][152:152][290:290]]',]

# List of Climate Model Names Corresponding To Files
climate_model = ['CanESM2', 'CNRM-CM5','CSIRO-Mk3-6-0','CCSM4','MIROC5','MPI-ESM-LR','MRI-CGCM3','GFDL-ESM2G','HadGEM2-ES']

def min_function(url,climate_model):
    r = requests.get(url)
    filename = 'tasmin85_' + f'{climate_model}' + '.nc'
    with open(filename,'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
        
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    executor.map(min_function, files, climate_model)
```

Comment: i think max_workers argument limit that

Comment: I thought so too, but it seems not to work for me.

Comment: i'm not sure but maybe its related to map function. Can you try submitting each thread rather than using map. Something like this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example

Comment: The code you posted limits the requests to two at a time. How did you determine that more requests are made? Have you tried adding prints before and after the `requests.get()` to see when a requests starts and finishes?

Comment: @KlausD. I did include prints, yes, but left them out for the example. What seems to be happening though is the `ThreadPoolExecutor` seems to not be respecting the `max_workers`. The result being that multiple requests are being made to the server consecutively rather than say, 2 times.

Comment: What else did you leave out for the example?

Comment: That is all. You should be able to copy/paste that code and see that it's not respecting the max_workers.

Comment: Starts two requests, takes forever. There have been a few bugs (e.g. [#24882](https://bugs.python.org/issue24882) regarding the worker queue. Are you using a recent Python version?

Comment: The requests are very long - they only download at kb/sec by design. I'm using 3.6. I just ran it again and it only submitted 2, which is fine. But if I were to stop and run it again, it could spit out a ton of files. It seems to inconsistently be using the correct number?

Comment: The code is fine. I tested it on 3.6 and 3.8 (linux, 64bit).

Comment: That's weird then, because on my system it seems to be inconsistent. It's odd that I can run it once and it will run with 2 workers, and then stopping and running again it will be out of control.